# My site is indexed, but not showing up in results

Tags: google-search, google-index, search-results

According Google Webmaster Tools, my site, `www.yomkippurshoes.com` is being indexed.

However, when I try to find it in results (e.g. type `site:yomkippurshoes.com` in Google), I don't see it in the results. This isn't an SEO issue as I'm not concerned about the ranking (yet).  I'm just not sure why it isn't being shown in the results at all.

[According to this article](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2642366?hl=en), Google will  not show the results if the site is down. However, mine isn't down.

Any thoughts on the disparity?

Comment: I can! http://i.gyazo.com/943c670015a3a863a309ea0c0bf1a1ab.png

Comment: Questions that are specific to one website are off-topic because they are unlikely to help future visitors. Examples include individual website reviews for SEO purposes and general website troubleshooting. See [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Site is indexed and is displayed in search results. Please check from the many questions and answers how to increase your rankings.

Comment: @JZapin I maintain a checklist for such issues: https://ligatures.net/content/expertise/site-not-ranking-checklist.html

Comment: Thanks for all the responses.  It is now being ranked.  It isn't in the first page, but it is at least in the index.  I guess there is a delay.